# Matching a string but ignoring an optional suffix?

Tags: .net, regex

I would like to capture the beginning of a string but ignore an optional suffix `View`.

Possible inputs:

```
Shell
ShellView
Console
ConsoleView
```

Expected outputs:

```
Shell
Shell
Console
Console
```

This expression is obviously wrong, the question mark makes everything captured by the first group:

```
(\w+)(View)?
```

If I use an expression like `(Shell)(View)?` it does work but then only for strings that begin with `Shell`, nothing else of course.

**Question:**

How should such regex pattern be written ?

Comment: And with `^(\w+?)(?:View)?$`? See [the regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/APdiI3/1).

Comment: My bad, you're absolutely right, thing is, I've tried this on regex101.com but for some reason it never matches no matter which flags I set. However, just tried in C# and indeed it does work perfectly, thank you!

Comment: What is the desired match if the string were `'ShellViewpoint'`?

Comment: @CarySwoveland Good question, haven't thought about that, actually this is for locating view models so it is expected that there are some conventions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use

```
^(\w+?)(?:View)?$
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/APdiI3/1). *Details*:

- `^` - start of string
- `(\w+?)` - Group 1: any one or more word chars, as few as possible
- `(?:View)?` - an optional non-capturing group matching a `View` char sequence one or zero times
- `$` - end of string.

See a [C# demo](https://ideone.com/sEzmSL):

```cs
var texts = new List<string> { "Shell", "ShellView", "Console", "ConsoleView" };
var rx = new Regex(@"^(\w+?)(View)?$"); 
foreach (var text in texts) 
{
    var match = rx.Match(text)?.Groups[1].Value;
    Console.WriteLine(match);
}
```

Output:

```
Shell
Shell
Console
Console
```

Comment: If you could elaborate on why it never matches in regex101.com that would be awesome!

Comment: @aybe I am not sure what does not work at regex101.com. Note the .NET regex support was added not so long ago, there may be some bugs.

Comment: Well, indeed there seems to be some bugs... I refreshed the page and it works, thanks Wiktor 

Answer (score 0):

Here is another way to do it, which seems to be fast (98 steps).

```
^\w+?(?=View$|$)
```

[Here](https://regex101.com/r/xDKw1Y/1) is the online demo.

---

- `^`: Start of the String
- `\w+?`: Matches any word character between one and unlimited times, as few as possible.
- `(?=)`: Positive lookahead.

  - `View$`: Matches `View` at the end of the string
  - `|`: Or
  - `$`: End of the string